# Serial and parallel circuits and power

Tags: power, voltage

If I have 12V of power, and wanted to power LEDs with a forward voltage of 2V, could I only power 6 of them?  Would I connect the cathode of one to the anode of the next, creating a kind of serial connection?  Or is there a way to have each LED be it's own loop?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it either way. Each LED can be its own loop, or you can do it in [image: series-parallel]

In series-parallel, you have multiple current loops.  Each loop can carry as many LEDs as you can power from your supply voltage. For example, if you had LEDs with a nominal 1.7Vf, then you would have 5 LEDs for a total of 8.5V. With a power supply voltage of 12V, a reasonable resistor choice for each branch would be (12 - 8.5)/.02 = 190. Closest standard 5% resistor value I can think of is 220 ohms which would give you 16mA per branch. Should be plenty bright enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are some basic rules regarding voltage and current:

- The current in a *series* circuit is *everywhere the same*
- The total current drawn by a *parallel* circuit equals the *sum of the different parallel connected circuits*

You can use 5 LEDs in series with a current limiting resistor (see the comments). You can also use multiple series of 5, in parallel, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6KQ1C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can also give every LED its own "loop". That is, you make sure no LEDs are connected in series with each other. That could be useful when you want to switch them on and off separately. Normally, an LED uses like 20mA on 2V (I'd say 2.5V, but well). You might want to check the datasheet on this to be sure.

Given that the LED takes 2V, that's 10V left to dissipate<sup>1</sup>. You'll use a series resistor for this. It has to take 10V at 20mA (the current in the series is the same everywhere), so you can calculate the resistance with \$R=\frac{V}{I}=\frac{10}{0.02}=2\text{k}\Omega\$. So the circuit would be like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR9KBC.png)</sup>

> <sup>1: dissipate, yes, in heat. This is *not* energy-efficient!</sup>

Comment: -1 Your first picture is not appropriate to post here. Not all LEDs have the same forward voltage and so the parallel branch with the lowest forward voltage will conduct a majority of the current, if not all of it. Secondly the circuit shows six supposed 2V LEDs. With a 12V supply you may just have the supply a little low and some LED strings a bit high on Vf. As a result those may not conduct at all. And finally you show no current limiting so any LEDs that happen to conduct will probably be fried. I suggest you replace the picture with 5 LEDs plus resistor in each branch.

Comment: "Not all LEDs have the same forward voltage" - do you mean little changes due to production issues? The OP talks about a 2V forward voltage. 5 LEDS + an R is a good idea, let me edit that in.

Comment: Yes, there will be variations of Vf for each LED even if they all are the same part number from the same batch.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I'm not sure if that will be such a huge difference, I've used something like the first circuit multiple times without issues. But you're probably right it isn't a good idea. I edited the current limiting resistor in.

Comment: @CamilStaps Actually, even with a single batch of a specific model number of the best brands of LEDs, there is a significant Vf variation between LEDs at a specific current, in practice. This is coming from my obsessive destructive testing of every aspect of LEDs over the years. :-)

Comment: This is very informative.  Thank you.  I do have a question.  In the first diagram, the series is limited to 5 LEDs and a 200 Ohm resistor, due to forward voltage.  What limits the number of parallel circuits I can have in this diagram?

Comment: @MichaelBlaustein The more parallel circuits, the higher the total current (see the second rule). You can add in as much parallel circuits as your voltage source can handle.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm still not sure I understand completely.  In your first diagram, what would a voltmeter read in the lower left corner?  Are there still 12V there?  Or does the first parallel circuit eat all the power?  If there are still 12V there, what prevents me from placing an infinite amount of parallel circuits in this diagram?

Comment: @MichaelBlaustein 12V, yes, it's connected to the voltage source _directly_. In theory, nothing prevents you from doing that. However, the total current drawn will increase, since the _total current drawn is the sum of all the series circuits you connected in parallel._ So in the end, your voltage source won't be able to handle the high current anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably connect the LEDs in parallel. Choose a current per LED (e.g. 10mA) and choose one resistor in series with the LEDs to get the desired current. The formula for the resistor is:
$$R = \frac{12V - 2V}{N\cdot10mA}$$

where \$N\$ is the number of LEDs. If you choose a different current, just replace the 10mA in the above formula by the new current.

Comment: Why shouldn't one connect the LEDs in parallel?

Comment: I actually wrote "you SHOULD probably connect the LEDs in parallel" (and not "should not"). (?)

Comment: Uh, yeah, sorry. Why should one do that? You're dissipating good energy with the series resistors.

Comment: Because otherwise the number of LEDs in series is restricted by the maximum voltage of the source. And you cannot exactly know the forward voltage (it depends on the current etc.). So I think it's safer to have a larger margin between the source voltage and the voltage drop across the LEDs and use resistor to get the appropriate current. Don't get me wrong, I wasn't criticizing the other answers. Just my opinion.

Comment: I understand (I'm not criticizing you either, just curious), but "otherwise the number of LEDs in series is restricted by the maximum voltage of the source" is **not true**. One can use multiple series circuits in parallel.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the number is restricted if you only use a series arrangement of LEDs. Of course you can have several such LED series circuits in parallel.

Comment: Okay, glad to hear that.

Comment: I think any series/parallel arrangement will work just fine if you leave some reasonable margin between the source voltage and the voltage across the LEDs. But I wouldn't do it without any series resistor.